# Can I Register SPWorkflowService on two Web Frontend Servers?

Tags: workflow-manager, workflow-manager-farm

I just installed a second SharEPoint Server and joined it to an existing farm, hosting all websites. Then I ran WorkFlow Manager to add the server to the workflow dbs of the farm and registered the workflow service using the new server's url. However, it seems like when I register on one server, it is removed from the other web front end. IS it possible to have it registered and running on both web front ends, if not, would I need to manually intervene in case of failover?

Answer (score 0):

You only run this cmdlet once on a farm. If you have two farms, you need to use a different Scope when running the cmdlet.

If you've already ran the cmdlet on one SharePoint server in the farm, you never need to run it again unless you're troubleshooting issues with WFM.

Comment: So IF I ran it on the original web front end server, and then added a new web front end server for failover, once the first server dies the workflows will stop working coz they are registered on that url, or am I totally wrong?

Comment: You're wrong. The URL is only used to establish registration with the farm (you could just use the Central Admin URL). Once you register, you don't need to re-register in normal operations.

Comment: ok so if i have
server 1 (wfe)
server 2 (wfe)
both hosting web applications and central admin, since they are used for failover
I register with http://centraladminurl.server1 , the workflows will work both on wfe 1 and wfe 2 right? and then if server 1 dies, workflows will continue to run normally?

Comment: Right. You should also make CA highly available, though :-)

Comment: how do I do that?

Comment: Hi Trevor  I registered the WF on central admin as you suggested, I will shut down one web front end now to test if workflows keep working and let you know - thanks